# Mocking Request.UserHostAddress for Unit Testing for WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I am writing Unit Test for my WEB API Service. I want to mock request from ip address. I am using Microsoft Unit Test.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private Mock<HttpContextBase> moqContext;
    private Mock<HttpRequestBase> moqRequest;

    [TestMethod()]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
       var controller = new TestController();
        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(moqContext.Object, new System.Web.Routing.RouteData(), controller);

    }
    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetupTests()
    {
        // Setup Moq
        moqContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        moqRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        moqContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(moqRequest.Object);
        moqContext.Setup(x => x.Request.UserHostAddress).Returns("192.111.1.1");
    }

}
```

I don't know how to proceed further, I am getting below error.

```
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1503  Argument 3: cannot convert from
> 'WebApplication1.Controllers.TestController' to
> 'System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase'   UnitTestProject1
```

Any help appreciated.
Is MOQ better than Rino, also, alternate ways for avoiding virtual methods for MOQ testing.

Updates 
Ok so the Controller is an API Controller as follows

```
// GET: api/Test
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            string s =HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
             ...Authentication/Authorization based on IP address
            return new string[] { s };
        }
```

I want to mock HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress in my Unit test so as to test different IP address. My question is how to set the mock IP address. I have found a link https://blog.slatner.com/geeky/mocking-request-userhostaddress-in-asp-net-mvc.html. but I couldn't figure out how to use. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What's your unit test criteria and can you show us the controller which you are mocking?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up the mock *request* object instead?

```
// moqContext.Setup(x => x.Request.UserHostAddress).Returns("192.111.1.1");  <-- not this
moqRequest.Setup(x => x.UserHostAddress).Returns("192.111.1.1")
```

Answer (score -1):

It means that your `TestController`class does not inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase`. So go back to the definition of your `TestController` and make sure it looks like

```
public class TestController: System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase
{ /* your code here */ }
```

Comment: I dont want to change my Web API code, I dont want to change my production code based on my unit test criteria.

Comment: "...for Unit Testing for WEB API" and Web API `!=` MVC